# Planner ORB visual SLAM

Tags: slam

I am using images collected from a car to run ORB-SLAM2 (https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) which utilize g2o to optimize car position and map points. I found there was sever scale shift in the SLAM results from my monocular data. So I would like to add constraints to make it more stable. One thing I can do is to assume the car was driving on a flat surface so it had a fixed y position. Basically, from frame to frame, the y position of the car did not change. However, I do not know how to add this to the SLAM code. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Odometry or Visual Inertial Odometry applications, sometimes the estimated trajectory may not be overlapped with the ground truth data since the ground truth and the estimated trajectory are expressed in different reference frames or the trajectory data is high-dimensional data. In such cases, trajectory alignment is performed. More detailed information can be found in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8593941):
"*A Tutorial on Quantitative Trajectory Evaluation for Visual(-Inertial) Odometry*"
Zichao Zhang, Davide Scaramuzza
IEEE IROS 2018